# Yii User Module Error on add new profile field

Tags: php, yii

i use Yii User Module, when i add new record at profiles_fields table "company"

when i make register i meet this error

```
Property "Profile.company" is not defined.



7         } elseif ($field->range) {
68             echo $form->dropDownList($profile,$field->varname,Profile::range($field->range));
69         } elseif ($field->field_type=="TEXT") {
70             echo$form->textArea($profile,$field->varname,array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50));
71         } else {
72             echo $form->textField($profile,$field->varname,array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>(($field->field_size)?$field->field_size:255)));
73         }
74          ?>
75         <?php echo $form->error($profile,$field->varname); ?>
76     </div>    
77             <?php
```

any one can solve that problem?

Comment: Show table structure and where this error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

check your `Profile` if it is have a `company` property or not, if not you should add it as an attribute